# How do I determine the target HArdware platform that my compiler is compiling for?

Tags: unix, compile

I have a centOS 5.3 box with intel Xeon processors. A friend of mine was looking around and said my binaries are being compiled with an AMD target. Doesn't ./configure (like when building apache) automatically detect if you have Intel or AMD and traget the correct platform? How do I tell which target platform the comiler is using definitively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the x86-64 was originally developed by AMD, but Intel has started using it, so the AMD nomenclature is hanging around even though its Intel hardware.